# Programmatically closing typeahead result display?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to find a way to programmatically close the typeahead result display and clear the input.

Clearing the input is as easy as adding the following in the `typeahead:closed` event handler:

`$(obj.currentTarget).val("");`

However, I just can't seem to find a way to close the dropdown. I have tried various things in the `typeahead:selected`, `typeahead:closed` and `typeahead:autocompleted` event handlers, but nothing works.

How can I close the result display using Javascript?

Comment: `$(YOUR_ID).html('').hide();`

Comment: @RPM what element is `YOUR_ID`?

Comment: `YOUR_ID` is the ID of the element you're trying to hide.  `<input id='typeahead'>` would be `$('#typeahead').html('').hide();`.

Comment: Although it's probably not going to be `<input>`, likely a `<div>`.  You'll have to look at the source code to see the name of the element that gets added by typeahead.js.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Adding `$(obj.currentTarget).trigger('blur');` in the aforementioned events will close the results display.